# gcc Nvapi compilation error

Tags: c++, gcc, nvidia

I'm trying to use NVAPI and I just included nvapi header file

```
#include <nvapi.h>
```

and I got a lot of errors like:

```
../../../../NVApi/nvapi.h:99:17: error: ‘__success’ initialized and declared 
‘extern’ [-Werror]
NVAPI_INTERFACE NvAPI_Initialize();
             ^
../../../../NVApi/nvapi.h:99:18: error: expected primary-expression before 
‘return’
NVAPI_INTERFACE NvAPI_Initialize();
              ^
../../../../NVApi/nvapi.h:99:38: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before 
‘NvAPI_Status’
NVAPI_INTERFACE NvAPI_Initialize();
```

It's possible to use nvapi with gcc?
                                      ^